# Newlines in Function Definition for iPython Terminal

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic, python-config

Using %paste, iPython takes newline characters in my function definition as the end of the function.  This isn't an issue when I code from someone else's machine.  I've looked through the config documentation and other sites; no luck.

```
def get_sheet(filepath, sheet_name):

    book = open_workbook(filepath)
    for name in book.sheet_names():
        if sheet_name in name.lower():
            sheet_name = name

    sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)

    return sheet

SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Many thanks =)

Comment: What version of IPython do you have? That works for me on master.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%cpaste`, which requires two dashes to exit the mode.